# CSS Multiple Inputs

Tags: css

Hi I'm new to CSS and wanna know how to do this I have this and for CSS I made it so every input gets affected

```
    <div class="inputWithIcon">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Uw leeftijd">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>

input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 3s;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #333;
}

.inputWithIcon input {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.inputWithIcon {
  position: relative;
}

.inputWithIcon i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 8px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.inputWithIcon i {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.inputWithIcon input:focus + i {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  transition: 3s;
}
```

Now I have a checkbox input and I don't want it to get changed by the other thing
how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:not()` in CSS. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
Or add a class to your inputs and rewrite your CSS, eg.

```
<input class="input-style-a">
<input class="input-style-b">


input.input-style-a { /* some styles */}
input.input-style-b { /* some styles */}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :not([type='checkbox'])

```
input:not([type='checkbox']) {
  width: 100%;
  ....
}
```

```css
input:not([type='checkbox']) {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 3s;
}

input:not([type='checkbox']):focus {
  border-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #333;
}

.inputWithIcon input:not([type='checkbox']) {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.inputWithIcon {
  position: relative;
}

.inputWithIcon i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 8px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.inputWithIcon i {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.inputWithIcon input:not([type='checkbox']):focus + i {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="inputWithIcon">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Uw leeftijd">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>


<div class="inputWithIcon">
  <input type="checkbox" placeholder="Uw leeftijd">
</div>
```